# Not able to add file to repo larger than 1.5 MB

Tags: java, file-io, mime-types, mime, rdf4j

Systeminformation:

Application Information
Application Name RDF4J-server 
Version 2.2 
Runtime Information : 
Operating System Linux 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64 (amd64) 
Java Runtime Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.8.0_102)

I'm using the RDF4J api wanting to write NTriples to a repository in RDF4J server.
The data is in a file and I can upload the file using workbench but using the api it throws an exception. This only occurs if the filesize is larger than 1.5MB. 
If I use curl it also works with files larger than 1.5MB.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: text/plain" --data-binary @central-ReadOnly.nt http://localhost:8080/rdf4j-server/repositories/testOfUpload/statements
```

So the question is. Why is failing on mimetype if file is larger than 1.5MB? 
Why is the file created as a text/plain; ? 
The file has been created as a .nt extension and I have added in /etc/mime.types the following

```
#MIME type                                      Extensions
application/n-triples                           nt
```

-

```
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.UpdateExecutionException: Unsupported MIME type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Message!!error executing transaction
org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryException: error executing transaction
at     org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sparql.SPARQLConnection.commit(SPARQLConnection.java:438)
at dk.skat.rdfconsolidation.Application.writeStatementsToRepository(Application.java:215)
at dk.skat.rdfconsolidation.Application.run(Application.java:72)
at dk.skat.rdfconsolidation.Application.main(Application.java:34)
```

Code:

```
protected void writeStatementsToRepository(String endpoint, String fileName) throws IOException {
    File inputfile = new File(fileName);

    Repository repo = new SPARQLRepository(endpoint);
    repo.initialize();

    try (RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection()) {
        con.begin();
        try {
            con.add(inputfile, null, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);
            con.commit();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!" + e.getCause());
            System.out.println("Message!!" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("endpoint" + endpoint);
            System.out.println("inputfile" + inputfile);
            System.out.println("fileName" + fileName);
            con.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried HTTPRepository instead of SPARQLRepository? Maybe this solves the issue for you.

Comment: Still strange exception though.

Comment: Always happy to help :D yes very strange, you should create an issue here https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues and then the rdf4j guys will take a look at it.